# Check which statistics were used in query optimization

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan, statistics

Is it possible to tell when statistics were last accessed by a query using T-SQL? I'm trying to ascertain what statistics are involved in a query, I know I can check the visual query plan but I wondered whether there was a table (or *tables*) with this information.

Answer (score 5):

When using the original (70) cardinality estimation model, undocumented trace flags **9204** and **9292** can be used to show which statistics were loaded during query optimization, as detailed in my post [How to Find the Statistics Used to Compile an Execution Plan](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/09/how-to-find-the-statistics-used-to-compile-an-execution-plan.html).

You can also use undocumented trace flag **8666** as described by Fabiano Amorim in [Statistics used in a cached query plan](https://blogfabiano.com/2012/07/03/statistics-used-in-a-cached-query-plan/).

For the updated cardinality estimation model (120 and later), undocumented trace flag **2363** shows a lot of useful information, including which statistics were loaded.

New for SQL Server 2017, the statistics objects used to compile and optimize a query are included directly in the execution plan. See [SQL Server 2017 Showplan enhancements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-2017-showplan-enhancements/) by Pedro Lopes.