# how to tell which statistics SQL server references in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, statistics, trace-flags

Is there a way to check in SQL Server 2016 which statistics the optimizer referenced when compiling a particular query?

My question is similar to [Check which statistics were used in query optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48890/how-to-check-what-stats-were-used-in-query),
except that I am using SQL Server 2016, which doesn't appear to support trace flags 9204 and 9292 as listed in [How to Find the Statistics Used to Compile an Execution Plan](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/09/how-to-find-the-statistics-used-to-compile-an-execution-plan.html) by Paul White. I tried them and nothing showed in my SSMS.

I googled to check why - and it sounded as if 2016 doesn't support them?